# How to give different input with different onclick, javascript?

Tags: javascript, web

```
var array1 = [
   "a","b","c"
]
document.getElementsByClassName("class").onclick = myFunction;
function myFunction(){
    var array2 = document.getElementsByClassName("class");
    videoContainer.attribute=array1[0];
}
```

this would work, but is there a way to make it easier and link the class array length with the other array("array 1" and "array 2"), like a for loop or something else

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you want to achieve?

Comment: You want to get the element in `array1` whose index corresponds to the length of `array2` is that it?

Comment: your code looks strange ! You're adding event listeners to an array !

Comment: My goal is to change an attribute that is called by the class when clicking different subjects. For example, <A class="a"> </A> <B class = "a"></B>, and an array[a,b],change the background color of <C></C> to a when click on A ,and change to b when click on B.

Comment: @AmmoPT I think so, by an onClick event.

Comment: this is what I have been working on: var popup = document.getElementById("popup")
function popupHidden(){
 popup.style.display = "none";
 }
var myVideo = [
 "http://player.youku.com/player.php/sid/XMzc5NzI0Mjc4NA==/v.swf", "http://player.youku.com/player.php/sid/XMzc5OTU2MzQ4OA==/v.swf"
];
var i;
var video = document.getElementsByClassName("video");
for (i = 0;i<video.length;i++){
video[i].onclick = videoShow;
 function videoShow(){
  var videoCon = document.getElementById("videoCon");
  popup.style.display = "block";
  videoCon.src=myVideo[0];
 }
}

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) is always useful.

Comment: @Teemu it is easy to do one element by one element, and my question is how to do it all together.

Comment: You don't, and the code snippet in the post doesn't do what you think it does. The only way is to iterate through the returned collection and "do it element by element". Just read the docs, you'll soon find out what it's all about.